# While nao valida ultimo array php

Tags: php, mysql

Alguem sabe porque o button do último registro do while nao executa a action do formulario?

```html
<?php
 while($dados_tabela = $consulta_tabela -> fetchObject()) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->nome; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->usuario; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->senha; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->email; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form name="editar_usuario" action="../php/editar_usuario.php" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_editar" value="<?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?>" />
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
            </form>
          </td>
          <td>
            <form name="excluir_usuario" action="../php/excluir_usuario.php" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_excluir" value="<?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?>" />
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Você não pode colocar o mesmo formulário dentro de um laço, coloque o nome do formulário e a id do form, como uma variável da chave, concatenando com os nomes.

Comment: Ivan, na verdade até "pode", mas é completamente NÃO recomendado por inumeros problemas haha

Comment: Pode só que ele sempre vai sobrescrever a informação.

Comment: @IvanFerrer , poderia me passar como ficaria essa alteração?

Comment: Porque não utiliza `foreach`?

Comment: Vou apresentar uma solução melhor, evitando esse loop de forms... pq isso realmente não é uma boa prática.

Comment: @IvanFerrer obrigado pela solução via javascript porem agora nao funcionou nenhum. eu nao queria passar por $_GET para nao ficar visivel na URL mas vou tentar chamar o $_GET na url de um iframe ou pelo include mas nao vem uma ideia de como implementar

Comment: eu editei, tinha uma variável a mais "form". que na verdade era o nome do form.

Comment: Tem como colocar a parte do código da query, e a saída de um `print_r( $consulta_tabela );` para avaliarmos? À propósito, não relacionado com a pergunta, mas dá pra dar uma boa enxugada nesse seu HTML depois, reorganizando a tabela de fora. Um bom teste é ver se não tem nenhum outro elemento da página com z-index maior que o botão desejado, coisa que não dá pra analisar só olhando seu código.

Comment: E retire os names excluir_usuario e editar_usuario dos forms, não tem serventia nesse caso, e gera nomes repetidos.

Comment: O problema de fazer isso: quando você envia a requisição post, o documento HTML procura o cabeçalho do <form>, cada form é um array e cada elemento do form é um outro array... se você coloca o mesmo nome, é o mesmo que pegar sempre a mesma chave do array, ele irá procurar o atributo desse array e não irá encontrar porque ficou em outro form de mesma chave. E ele não faz essa distinção e nem essa mesclagem.

Comment: exatamente @IvanFerrer acho que vou colocar nome do form concatenado com o id da linha recuperada na consulta para assim nao ficar o mesmo nome do form em todas as linhas.

Comment: fiz o que disse mas sem sucesso tambem. no caso em cada linha ficaria um form com name diferente. sem sucesso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema pode ser resolvido desta maneira, coloque junto a biblioteca do jquery:

```
    <?php

     $url_editar = '../php/editar_usuario.php';
     $url_excluir = '../php/excluir_usuario.php';

     while ($dados_tabela = $consulta_tabela -> fetchObject()) {
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->nome; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->usuario; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->senha; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->email; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <button type="button" id="editar_<?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-edit" data-id="<?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
              </td>
              <td>
               <button type="button" id="excluir_<?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-delete" data-id="<?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>      
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
<form name="editar_usuario" action="<?php echo $url_editar?>" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" id="id_editar" name="id_editar" value="" />
</form>
<form name="excluir_usuario" action="<?php echo $url_excluir?>" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" id="id_excluir" name="id_excluir" value="" />
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('.btn-edit').on('click', function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
       $('#id_editar').val(id);
       $('[name="editar_usuario"]').submit();

  });

 $('.btn-delete').on('click', function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
       $('#id_excluir').val(id);
       $('[name="excluir_usuario"]').submit();
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Continua a não funcionar o ultimo button conforme imagem do link http://www.prestoexpress.com.br/erro.jpg

Comment: Ele esta pegando o click pela classe do botao?

Comment: Não exatamente, quando clicar no botão, ele executa uma função que captura os dados contidos nesse botão e envia para o formulário, e depois o submete, fora do loop, isso não é ajax.

Comment: Ajax seria um procedimento de requisição.

Comment: Porque negativou a pergunta, explique o problema.

Comment: Nao entendi @Ivan, nao negativei, alias sou meio novato por aqui ainda aprendendo as regras. esta melhorando o codigo com as alterações que voce citou

Comment: Alguém anda negativando de bobagem por aí

Comment: Já dei UP na sua resposta.

Answer (score -2):

Penso que seria melhor se você fizesse dessa forma, pois repetir o `<form>` para cada registro não é uma boa prática.

```html
<?php
 while($dados_tabela = $consulta_tabela -> fetchObject()) {

  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->nome; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->usuario; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->senha; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dados_tabela->email; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="../php/excluir_usuario.php?id_editar=<?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?>">Editar</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="../php/excluir_usuario.php?id_excluir=<?php echo $dados_tabela->id; ?>">Excluir</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Pois é... eu queria evitar o $_GET ... mas acho que seria a única solução de momento

Comment: Entendo... Uma outra alternativa é fazer via JS, não rola?

Comment: Pensei em colocar o $_GET em um iframe sendo assim nao fica visivel na URL ... mas ainda estou pensando em como fazer essa jogada ou ainda em um include . aff

Comment: Algum motivo para não fazer via Ajax?

Comment: Nenhum motivo Ademilson, so que estou pensando em como criar essa função e como chamar ela da outra pagina.

Comment: A melhor maneira seria fazer uma implementação ajax. Com certeza. usando `$.post('request.php', {id:id, acao:'excluir'}, function(e){ var rtn =  $.parseJSON(e);  console.log(s.msg) })` tipo isso ou `$.ajax({...});`

Comment: boa @IvanFerrer nao tinha pensado. pensei em passar por session o que vc acha? na verdade eu queria evitar javascript e $_GET

Comment: @EzequielTavares você pode usar JavaScript e enviar via post com ajax ;)
Ajax resolveria vários problemas como por exemplo o "atualizar" desnecessário da página no caso do "deletar"...